# Can't run mopidy docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu-server, mopidy

I'm trying to install mopidy docker ( https://github.com/wernight/docker-mopidy) that would play music and send sound to pulseaudio. I'm trying to compose it with tihs:

```
mopidy:
  container_name: mopidy
  image: wernight/mopidy
  volumes:
    - ${USERDIR}/kontit/mopidy/local:/var/lib/mopidy/local
    - ${USERDIR}/kontit/mopidy/config:/var/lib/mopidy/.config/
    - /run/user/{$PUID}/pulse:/run/user/105/pulse:ro
  ports:
    - 6600:6600
    - 6680:6680
  user: "${PUID}:${PGID}"
```

But I can't get container to run and in docker-mopidy log there are some permission errors in python:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/mopidy/.cache/mopidy'
```

Any good ideas what I'm doing wrong?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Any luck been trying for days

Comment: Got the same issue... Did you happen to find a solution ?